# Python's equivalent to PHP's null coalesce operator and shorthand ternary operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking here and couldn't find anything: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Two examples of PHP that come in handy a lot:

```php
echo $count ?: 10; //prints $count if $count is not empty string, null, false or 0, otherwise prints 10.

echo $a ?? $b ?? 7; //prints $a if $a is defined and not null, otherwise will print $b, otherwise 7
```

Are there equivalent operators in Python? Note:

```
a if condition else b
```

does not really replace the shorthand ternary operator, because condition and return value are specified in one element in PHP in the shorthand version.

Comment: `a or b` evaluates to `a` if `a` is truthy, `b` otherwise. Not exactly the same but effective in many cases.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/

Comment: `a or b` won't work if `a` is undefined

Comment: @jonrsharpe was this implemented?

Comment: @Toskan: Asking for something that works with undefined variables… it's just not going to happen. In Python, using an undefined variable will raise an exception. If you want to avoid that, somehow, you're going to need to write a bunch of boilerplate.  Or you could just initialize your variables to `None`.

Comment: What do you mean *"if a is undefined"*? If that identifier doesn't exist in scope it's a `NameError` however you do it. And no, PEP505 hasn't been implemented.

Comment: it's a `NameError` in python. It is not an error in other programming languages to have undefined variables in ` ?? ` constructs

Comment: @Toskan: It’s an error in other languages too—just try to use the null coalescing operator in C#, Swift, or Kotlin and you'll find that it simply doesn't work with undefined variables. Python works the same way, it's simply not designed to make it easy to work with undefined variables, if you want a null value use `None` instead of undefined.

Comment: @DietrichEpp C# _is statically typed_ just like swift or kotlin. Yes, you cannot just throw around variables in a statically typed language, I don't need to explain that do I... but why not allow it in dynamically typed languages? it is exactly there for that reason. If you do `a = None; x = a ?? b;` well why would you do that anyway?

Comment: @Toskan: If you find it weird that you have to explain that C# is statically typed, imagine how weird I think it is that I need to explain that using an undefined variable in Python is an error. That should be obvious, just like it's obvious that C# is statically typed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp please don't be upset dietrich. I will give you an example, and I want your honest opinion about it.
`current_job = d['job'] ?? 'No job defined';`
can you see a use case for this? the thing is, I was using `??` in PHP _all the time_. Everywhere. For setting default values. It is _pure joy_ to not have to _each time_ check if the value exists. If it does exist -> use it. If it does not exist, use a different value... oh wait... first check if that different value exists! then use it. Else, check if a different value exists..

Comment: I'm flattered that you want to talk about my feelings, but Stack Overflow is a forum for discussing programming. In Python, `d['job]'` is not undefined, it is a `KeyError`. If you want to get `None` out of it, you would use `d.get('job')`, you could use `d.get('job') or 'No job defined'` if that's your style, or you could use `d.get('job', 'No job defined')` which is the most likely option. So you can see that the operator exists in Python, but you can't use a value which throws an exception in an expression where it must be evaluated.

Comment: This is actually the same way that PHP works. In PHP, you can't use the `??` operator if the left-hand side throws an exception. Python does the same thing, it's just that `d['job']` will throw an exception in Python and it won't throw an exception in PHP. So you have to use `d.get('job')`, which returns `None` if the key doesn't exist. Python has no concept of an "undefined" value, only undefined variables, which when evaluated throw an exception.

Comment: If I'm going to be perfectly honest here, Python seems to be doing a pretty good job of doing exactly what you want to do (use `.get()` or whatever), but your primary complaint seems to be that Python doesn't work the same way PHP does, which isn't really an actionable complaint.

Comment: actually php does throw a notice and notices are nothing else than errors. The most popular framework fatal *poof* die on a notice. And I think it's a good thing. I would argue actually that phps `??` didn't even go far enough. Or at least offer a way to go even further. `$x->doesntExist() ?? 'default'` does throw a fatal error. It would have been better to allow a way to disable that. Because `$x->doesntExist ?? 'default'` does not throw an error.

Comment: but one can argue about that I guess... but back to python. Now `.get` does seem to do exactly what I was looking for indeed. But it only works on dictionaries doesn't it? what if I have a view template block that I want to reuse in different workflows, with slightly different objects / variables. I don't want to refactor all calls to the template block just for the sake of that new workflow, I just want to fall back to other values / objects in case I am in a different work flow. Plain variables. I mean for dict yeah, perfect solution. What about everything else? I am not a php fan really.

Comment: I would even go a step further. The `.get` method of the dictionary of python is nothing else than the confirmation that this is an annoying problem. An annoying problem nobody wants to deal with because it's stupid and trivial. And verbose as hell too. It would be time for dynamic typed languages, to embrace that fact, and to make it easier to work with objects and variables that you don't know what they are and if said function exists or not. `??` would be a step in the right direction. And I am all aboard the type hinting train, don't get me wrong. _All aboard_. But there are exceptions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `or` operator returns the first truth-y value.

```
a = 0
b = None
c = 'yep'

print(a or 'nope')
print(b or 'nope')
print(c or 'nope')
print(b or c or 'nope')
> nope
> nope
> yep
> yep
```

Comment: @Toskan: Yes it does. If `a` is undefined, `True or a` is still `True`. But using undefined variables in Python is not very idiomatic, so you will run into issues elsewhere.

Comment: which probably is better any way. Even though there are exceptions. It's not a common thing or a good thing in php anyway. But there are use cases when reusing templates in different work flows where you don't want to refactor all calls to the template itself. Then I guess that or operator comes in handy

Comment: actually no, undefined will still throw an error in this case. Which would make you force to check `a` for existence and if not, setting None to it. Waste of time and I consider hand holding the programming language... unless I am overlooking something

Answer (score -2):

In Python there is a way to do ternary operations:

```
print((b, a)[a])  # if a: prints a; otherwise prints b
```

#### Explanation

The options are in a tuple : `(b, a)` the [condition] will determine either we call element at rank 0 (condition is false) or 1 in the tuple (condition is true).

#### Examples

```
a = False
b = "youpi"
print((b, a)[a])
# youpi

condition = "Thirsty"
print(("Foo" , "Bar")[condition == "Thirsty"])
# Bar
```

Comment: can you give a simple example? a complete one! with strings for example

Comment: This is barely shorter and ten times less readable than `a if a else b`; particularly, you have to repeat `a` (which might be a complex expression)

Comment: @tobias_k it is 69% (9/13*100) shorter so yes it looses in readability. Besides, i don't see your point concerning repeating a, don't you ?

Comment: It is 69% shorter provided that `a` and `b` are both just one character long. If they are longer, then the difference becomes much smaller. The point about repeating `a` is that `a` could in fact be more like `stuff.calculate(db.lookup())`

Comment: @tobias_k don't you repeat `a` in `a if a else b` ?

Comment: That's why OP said that he does not want it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148989/discussion-between-trolldejo-and-tobias-k).